# Redirect specific user role to specific site after login?

Tags: php, customization

I have a function which kind of works.
It will not work the first time when cookies are cleared. But the next time I will get redirected after login. Why is that?

```
function role_user_redirect_login($username, $user){
    if(array_key_exists('user', $user->caps)){
        wp_redirect(admin_url('edit.php?post_type=test', 'https'), 301);
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('wp_login', 'role_user_redirect_login', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the filter [`login_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) instead of `wp_login`:

```
function role_user_redirect_login($redirect_to, $request, $user){
    if(array_key_exists('user', $user->caps)){
        return admin_url('edit.php?post_type=test', 'https');
    }

    return $redirect_to;
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'role_user_redirect_login', 10, 3);
```

Comment: I tried this, and still end up in the "Your profile" screen. I have disabled access to the dashboard page for this user role (that's why I don't end up on the dashboard). If I log out and try to login again I will be redirected to the correct page. So it seems like when there are no cookies it will not redirect, but when I have cookies from the site it will work!

Comment: Maybe another plugin or theme hooks into this. Could you try a higher priority? And i made a little mistake: it should be `add_filter` and not `add_action`.

Comment: I think I might have narrowed it down. I use this on a multisite. If I go to example.com/wp-admin and login, the redirect doesn't work (I end up on the Profile page). If I go to example.com/mysite/wp-admin and login the redirect works fine! So there is something missing in the redirection maybe? EDIT: I tried both your suggestions without any difference! The cookie problem I thought it was, was that when I logged out and tried again I was at example.com/mysite/wp-admin when doing the second attempt!

Comment: It seems like the user gets redirected to _example.com/wp-admin/edit.php_ at first, but has no access to this page and gets redirected again to profile screen. At the second attempt the user gets redirected to _example.com/mysite/wp-admin/edit.php_ where he has access. So the redirect filter works fine, but the destination url is different

Comment: Can you provide me the URL of your site?

Comment: Sorry, I only have my site locally. Your description sound logical. But is it possible to solve it? Can you add something to the code that adds the current site to the URL?

Comment: Maybe [`get_site_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/) will help you. I don't have any experience with multisite so i'm not sure what's the correct way to achieve this.